# Calling WebService with Voting Buttons in Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook

Is it possible to call external webservice with in-built voting buttons or through some buttons in HTML email?

There will be a HTML mail with a button and on clicking it need to call the external webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Outlook does not run any scripts or submit forms from the HTML body of email messages.

Comment: Can you suggest alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: Unless you can install an addin on the client side, a link in the email is the best you can get.